# struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes

Tags: python

I am very new to Flatbuffers and improving my knowledge on Python so forgive me if I am overlooking something simple.

I am trying to get the sample Monster app working on Python but am receiving the following error:
**struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes**

I am using the files from the tutorial, generated the code using flatc and reading the Monster data file. When I try to access the data using "**monster.Mana()**" it shoots me an error msg.

Here is the code I am using, which cannot be simpler.
I have tried the code with both versions 2.7 & 3.6 and get the same error :-(

```
import MyGame  # refers to generated code
import MyGame.Example  as example
import MyGame.Example.Color  # refers to generated code
import MyGame.Example.Monster  # refers to generated code
import MyGame.Example.Weapon  # refers to generated code
import MyGame.Example.Vec3  # refers to generated code

buf = open('monsterdata.json', 'rb').read()
buf = bytearray(buf)
monster = MyGame.Example.Monster.Monster.GetRootAsMonster(buf, 0)

mana = monster.Mana()
```

Error msg:

```
color = monster.Mana()
```

File "/project/sample/MyGame/Example/Monster.py", line 34, in Mana
    o = flatbuffers.number_types.UOffsetTFlags.py_type(self._tab.Offset(6))
  File "/home/colin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flatbuffers/table.py", line 37, in Offset
    vtable = self.Pos - self.Get(N.SOffsetTFlags, self.Pos)
  File "/home/colin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flatbuffers/table.py", line 93, in Get
    return flags.py_type(encode.Get(flags.packer_type, self.Bytes, off))
  File "/home/colin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flatbuffers/encode.py", line 24, in Get
    return packer_type.unpack_from(memoryview_type(buf), head)[0]
struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes

I am sure I am doing something stupid and would appreciate some help.

rgds
Colin

Answer (score 1):

After some further tests and taking a step back to review what the actual problem was I realised myself what I was doing wrong.

The code I posted was reading the json file and converting to binary form instead of reading a binary form generated using flatc. This is of course not going to work and was causing the error. After rectifying the code to read the binary data all worked as expected.